# How to compute a running cor.test() in a data.frame with NA values in R?

Tags: r, correlation, na

I'm trying to do a **running()** correlation between my daily climate data, and the problem is that I have many missing values (NA) in my data.frame. I'm using the **cor.test()** because I need to get the ***p.values***. For example in some days I don't have precipitation or humidity values, and I would like to know how to compute this running correlation with my temperature data, but omitting the NA values.

Here an example with NA values:

```
library(gtools)
df <- data.frame(temp=rnorm(100, 10:30), prec=rnorm(100, 1:300), humi=rnorm(100, 1:100))

df$prec[c(1:10, 25:30, 95:100)] <-NA
df$humi[c(15:19, 20:25, 80:90)] <-NA

corPREC <- t(running(df$temp, df$prec, fun = cor.test, width=10, by=10))
corHUMI <- t(running(df$temp, df$humi, fun = cor.test, width=10, by=10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `complete.cases` to get a logical vector of complete rows (`TRUE` = complete); then subsetting inside ad-hoc function used for testing too

```
library(gtools)
df <- data.frame(temp=rnorm(100, 10:30), prec=rnorm(100, 1:300),
                 humi=rnorm(100, 1:100))

df$prec[c(1:10, 25:30, 95:100)] <-NA
df$humi[c(15:19, 20:25, 80:90)] <-NA

my.fun <- function(x,y) {
    my.df <- data.frame(x,y)
    my.df.cmpl <- my.df[complete.cases(my.df), ]

    # 3 complete obs is the minimum for cor.test
    if (nrow(my.df.cmpl)<=2) {
        return(rep(NA, 4))
    } else {
        my.test <- cor.test(my.df.cmpl$x,my.df.cmpl$y)
        return(c(my.test$statistic, my.test$p.value,
                 my.test$conf.int))
    }

}

corPREC <- t(running(df$temp, df$prec, fun = my.fun, width=10, by=10))
corHUMI <- t(running(df$temp, df$humi, fun = my.fun, width=10, by=10))
```

you could also consider

```
my.test <- cor.test(~ x + y, na.action = "na.exclude", data = my.df)
```

but you can't handle too-few-rows situations (in a straightforward manner).

Comment: It might be a bit severe to overwrite the entire dataset, don't you think?

Comment: @BondedDust sure thanks (some days i'm a bit too draconian :) ) , edited

Comment: Thanks @Luca Braglia but the idea is not to remove the NA rows, it is ignore the NA values. For example, like when I compute the same running function with a sum (`fun = sum`),the results give me NA values in the periods when was not possible compute it. The problem is that I cann't remove those days when only in one variable I don't have data.

Comment: @DarwinPC sorry, fixed

Comment: thanks a lot @LucaBraglia yours R knowledge are amazing!! it works, but with the code line `my.test <- cor.test(~ x + y, na.action = "na.exclude", data = my.df)` I don't understand what you mean. Is it to use inside the function?

Comment: @DarwinPC yes, inside the function. And no, these are the real Chuck Norris of R programming! :)  http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/208/r