# How to get the values separated by a comma from a List?

Tags: r

I would like to complete some analysis, I have already extracted in a new List object (named "NAcol") the number of columns with NA values (because this columns do not let me run the *cor.test()* function).

ok, this is my List:

```
> NAcol
[[1]]
 [1]  38  45  52  55  56  57  58  59  60 
[10] 101 102 103 104 105 118 119 120 131 
[19] 134 136 137


>
```

then, I would like to use the numbers of this List separated by a comma to exclude the columns of my data.frame to run my correlation.

That is what I would like to have:

```
cor.test(mydata[,2], mydata[,-c(38, 45, 52, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
                               101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 118, 119, 120, 131, 
                               134, 136, 137 ] )
```

as you can see, I want to exclude all these columns, which are the numbers of my List *"NAcol"*.

I don't know how or which function to use, I have tried the functions unlist() and split() without success.

I will appreciate very much your help.

Darwin

Comment: The `NAcol` list has one element which is a vector. So if you use `mydata[, -NAcol[[1]]]`, you should be ok.

Comment: or use `mydata[,-unlist(NAcol)]`.

Comment: You know that `x` and `y` in `cor.test.default` must have the same length, right?  This seems drastic just to get a vector the same length as `mydata[,2]`. You might want to use the formula method, it has a subset argument

Comment: @PeterDee and @ Marat Talipov That's exactly what I wanted, thanks :)    @ Richard Scriven I don't understand very well what you mean, all my columns have the same length, I'm running a loop-for to extract each p-value of my correlations to put these into a new data.frame.

Comment: @DarwinPC - Well if you do `data[,2]` on a data frame, you get a vector with length `nrow(data)`, but if you get more than one column back from the subset, the length will be `ncol(data[, subset])`.  A data frame's `length()` is its number of columns.  I just meant that it might cause issues later.

Answer (score 2):

The NAcol is a list containing one element which is an atomic vector. You can access this vector using the `[[` function:

```
> NAcol <- list(1:10)
> NAcol
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> NAcol[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

And then use it however you wish.

Edit: but `cor.test` only makes sense for numeric vectors of the same length. As Richard notes, from `?cor.test`:

> x, y: numeric vectors of data values.  ‘x’ and ‘y’ must have the
>             same length.

So instead of filtering out columns, you can filter out rows with `NA`s using the `complete.cases` function, or use the `na.action` parameter of `cor.test` - see here a similar question: [How to compute a running cor.test() in a data.frame with NA values in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281389/how-to-compute-a-running-cor-test-in-a-data-frame-with-na-values-in-r). Then you can examine the correlation between pairs of columns with complete rows.